# Why is$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-n)^2}$ continuously differentiable?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Basically the title. It is easy to show that f(x) converges for any real x that aren’t positive integers, so we only allow these values. It does not converge uniformly, however.

Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "non-integral", but keep in mind that fhe singularities occur only for positive integers. The series is convergent for any $x <  1$.

Comment: Yes true, I just mean that x isn’t an integer, but as you say the problem just occurs for positive ones

Comment: indeed, even converging uniformly it doesn't ensure that the function will be differentiable

Answer (score 1):

If $x_0\notin\mathbb{Z}$ then there exists $\varepsilon >0$ and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 -1 <x_0 -2\varepsilon <x_0 <x_0 +2\varepsilon <n_0.$ The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-n)^2 } $$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2}{(x-n)^3 } $$
converges uniformly on the interval $[x_0-\varepsilon , x_0 +\varepsilon]$ and hence $f$ is differentioable at $x_0$ and $f'$ is continous at $x_0.$

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem that says that for any sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of differentiable functions if $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $f_n'\to g$ locally uniformly for some functions $f$ and $g$, then $f_n\to f$ locally uniformly and $f'=g$. In your case you can set $f_n(x):=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(x-k)^2}$, then its easy to check that the theorem holds. Moreover, its immediate to see that $f'$ is also continuous.